# how to modify pixels of QBitmap

Tags: qt, mask, qimage, qpixmap

I want to work with masks on a `QImage`.
To handle the mask, I have a `QBitmap`. Now I'm looking for a fast way to do this things:

1. Invert the Bits of the mask
2. Set pixels of the mask to a new value

is there a fast way to do this? Or can I only use a `QPainter` Object to modify the `QBitmap`?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [`QImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QImage.html) with the format set to [`QImage::Format_Mono`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum). This way you create a 1-bit per pixel image you can use as a mask.

1. For inverting the pixels, use the [`invertPixels`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#invertPixels) method.
2. `QImage` bits can be accessed using the [`bits`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#bits) or [`scanLine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#scanLine) methods.

To use the `QImage` as a mask, you'll have to convert it to a `QPixmap` first:

```
QPixmap mask = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
painter.setClipRegion(QRegion(mask));
```

Since `QImage::Format_Mono` encodes the pixels MSB first (means first pixel will be stored in most significant bit of the first byte) with 8 pixels/byte, you'll need some bit-magic to access the correct bit for the given x/y position:

```
int GetPixel(const QImage& img, const int x, const int y) const
{
    const uchar mask = 0x80 >> (x % 8);
    return img.scanLine(y)[x / 8] & mask ? 1 : 0;
}

void SetPixel(QImage& img, const int x, const int y, const int pixel)
{
    const uchar mask = 0x80 >> (x % 8);
    if (pixel)
        img.scanLine(y)[x / 8] |= mask;
    else
        img.scanLine(y)[x / 8] &= ~mask;
}
```

Of course, don't use a function like `SetPixel` when you're manipulating a lot of pixels on the same row, as you don't want to lookup `scanLine(y)` for each pixel. Be creative!

Comment: thank you. I had this idea, too. But than I must convert the QImage each time to a QBitmap, to use it as a mask. Or how can I use the Qimage as a mask? (In time i used the method `setClipRegion()` of the `QPainter` to set up the mask)

Comment: Problem is that `setMask` is also an expensive operation, because the `QBitmap` still needs to be converted into a device dependant `QPixmap`. So maybe it's better that you only update the `QPixmap` mask when the mask has changed (unless you change it for each paint). Maybe you can use one of the [`Composition Modes`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html#composition-modes) of the painter (doesn't seem to work for OpenGL painter though)

Comment: the `Composition Mode` helps me. Currently I'm use the `setPixel` method of the `QImage`, but I think if I want to modify a large count of pixels the bit opertion is faster. The problem is, that `bits()` only return a pointer with `uchar`. Can you say me, how to set the the value of pixel x?

Comment: Manipulating images with `getPixel`/`setPixel` is terribly slow. For accessing the correct pixel in a 1bpp format, you need some bitshift/mask magic. Will update my answer.

Comment: Now it works perfect. I only had a problem with the QRegion in Qt 5.3. There I can't create a region with a QPixmap. But I can create a QBitmap from the QImage (QBitmap ::fromImage)